# disable quick edit mode for console from c++

Tags: c++, windows, console

I am trying to disable the quick edit mode of my console by my c++ program because in my application i don't want any selection. I also do not want any pause, as when someone clicks with this mode on it pauses the game. I have looked online and some documentation but i don't know what i have been doing wrong.
I first tried below code from another question on stack overflow it didn't work.

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>
using namespace std;


int main(){
    HANDLE hInput;
    DWORD prev_mode;
    GetConsoleMode(hInput, &prev_mode); 
    SetConsoleMode(hInput, prev_mode & ~ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE);

    cout<<"The quick edit mode stopped now press any key to re enable it"<<endl;
    _getch();
    SetConsoleMode(hInput, prev_mode);
    cout<<"Quick edit mode reenabled click any key to exit";
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

then i looked up [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode) and their i found something like this for `SetConsoleMode`.

> This flag enables the user to use the mouse to select and edit text.
>
> To enable this mode, use ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE |
>   ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS. To disable this mode, use ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS
>   without this flag.

Then i replaced `~ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE` with `ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS` and same result again i want to know what i am doing wrong. 
I want to disable quick edit mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very silly mistake in the code. The problem with the code is that `hInput HANDLE` wasn't initialized with `STD_INPUT_HANDLE` and therefore the method `SetConsoleMode` wasn't working. The working code is as below.

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>
using namespace std;


int main(){
    HANDLE hInput;
    DWORD prev_mode;
    hInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    GetConsoleMode(hInput, &prev_mode); 
    SetConsoleMode(hInput, prev_mode & ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS);
    cout<<"The quick edit mode stopped now press any key to re enable it"<<endl;
    _getch();
    SetConsoleMode(hInput, prev_mode);
    cout<<"Quick edit mode reenabled click any key to exit";
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're clearing all other flags. You want this instead: `ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS | (prev_mode & ~ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE)`. It's possible for extended flags to be disabled while quick-edit mode is enabled (e.g. if the mode was set to 7 in a previous call), so we have to explicitly include `ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS`.

Comment: Also, remember the error checking in your actual code. It's possible for standard I/O to be redirected to pipes or disk files, so you can't blindly assume that console functions such as `GetConsoleMode` and `_getch` will succeed. You need a fallback for non-console I/O.

Comment: Thank you for this. It solved a problem I'm having testing at the command line.